# Relatively prime numbers are prime

Tags: prime-numbers, totient-function, coprime

The problem is to find all numbers $n$ such that all numbers $k>1$ smaller than $n$ and coprime with $n$ are prime.

Comment: Do you have examples of such $n$ which are not too small?

Comment: The two formulations differ in meaning though: The only number $1<k<n$ coprime to $n=6$ is $k=5$, but $\phi(6)-1=4\ne 3=\pi(6)$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yep sorry, it is the non mathematical way...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen But I have to find all $n$ such that it is the case!

Answer (score 4):

Let $n$ have the property and let $p$ be the smallest prime *not* dividing $n$. Then $n<p^2$ as otherwise $\gcd(p^2,n)=1$ destroys the property.
On the other hand, this implies that $n$ is a multiple of  the product of all primes $<p$.

For $p\ge13$, by Bertrand's postulate, the prime preceding $p$ is $>\frac p2$ and the one preceding that is $>\frac p4$ (and $>5$). Hence $p^2>2\cdot 3\cdot5\cdot \frac  p4\cdot\frac p2=\frac{15}{4}p^2$, contradiction.

But also for $p=11$, we find $11^2=121>2\cdot3\cdot 5\cdot 7=210$, contradiction.

For $p=7$, we only get $n<49$ and $2\cdot3\cdot 5=30\mid n$,. Instead of a contradiction, this implies $n=30$. We verify that this does indeed have the property.

For $p=5$, we get $6\mid n<25$, so $n\in\{6,12,18,24\}$.
For $p=3$, we get $2\mid n<9$, so $n\in\{2,4,6,8\}$.
For $p=2$, we get $n<4$.

In summary:
The $n$ with this property are precisely
$$ n\in\{1,2,3,4,6,8,12,18,24,30\}.$$